# Netsuite Customization of Prospect Form

Tags: customization, netsuite

I need to customize the Prospect Form in such way that the fields from subtabs like (Relationship-Contact are sitting on the main tab). We need to use this form and add fields in a sequential order. Also I need some of those fields to fill in customer form once prospect is converted. I have been using Netsuite only a few weeks but have used other systems where I could customize fields from related tables with a drag and drop functionality.Is there such a thing in Netsuite?
Thank you

Comment: what do you exactly mean by `I need some of those fields to fill in customer form once prospect is converted.` ? Does it mean you want some kind of sourcing ?

Comment: There are standard fields and a lot of customized fields that need to flow through to the Customer record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prospects and Customers are just stages of the same underlying record. Information you fill in for a prospect will still be there if the prospect converts to a customer.

As far as entry forms go the Netsuite help is not bad in this area. See https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N2853340.html for how to start to customize your entry forms. In particular check the section called "Moving Fields and Lists between Subtabs"

You can't control sequential data entry without a client script or possibly a workflow but the help link above will get you started on putting the fields in the logical entry order.

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't work, script would be the way to go but i'm affraid I don't have the skills to do it and the consultants have no idea without engaging some developer. Thanks for the input

Comment: If you need to enable some fields based on the entries in previous fields you could probably use a workflow. However a Client script on Netsuite isn't that difficult and they do have a number of examples. As well there are a lot of code samples on usergroup.netsuite.com. Otherwise feel free to contact me via my Stack Overflow profile as I am "some developer".

Comment: Guess I will have to engage a developer after all. @bknights,thanks for the advice (I will send you an email regarding this)

Answer (score 2):

While in your prospect form that you want to update select 'Customize' from the top right. Then 'Customize Form'.

You'll see a button at the top called "Move elements between subtabs". Use this to move items around. After you move them you may want to go to the "Screen Fields" sub tab under the "Main" section and adjust the positioning of all the fields on your main form because when you move items between tabs they don't necessarily fall where you want them to.

As far as your fields flowing to the Customer, they will flow just fine because as someone else mentioned, a prospect record is an entity record (like customer and lead) so the record is promoted from lead to prospect then finally customer.

I agree with the other answer, get used to NetSuite help. I make a shortcut to Suite Answers, Schema Browser, SuiteScript API and SuiteScript Examples for quick reference. The NetSuite videos aren't too bad either worth looking at.

Comment: I have already tried that option but Contact is sitting under Lists (Next to the Field tab)  then Relationship and then I can see the Contact Field but  I cant move it across to the Main. Thanks for the advice anyway

Answer (score 0):

To move standard 'Lists' like Relationships, Contacts, Transactions etc this is also on the **Move Entry Form Elements,** look for the **Lists** subtab, next to **Fields.**